# Got the wrong DNS servername which is in another subnet

Tags: networking, dns

So the network works as follows:

```
My PC ---(Ethernet) Raspberry Pi (wlan) --- Router
```

On the RPi I run a Busybox Linux. For the dhcpd.conf on eth0 of the RPi, I set option dns 8.8.8.8. I build a nat between Ethernet and wlan.

But weird is, after I connect the RPi with the router, I cannot visit internet with my PC, but I can ping 8.8.8.8. Then I checked the DNS server, it shows the DNS servername on my PC is "192.168.1.1", and it is the IP of ther Router, which is in another subnet and of course my PC cannot find it.

What should I do? It seems I have to set a dns proxy on the RPi? Or how could the DNS servername be passed correctly in this case?

Comment: If the PC can reach the Internet, why can't it find the DNS server?

Comment: @JohanMyréen The thing is the DNS server name on the PC is shown as "192.168.1.1", which is the IP of the router. And it's a local IP not a public IP.

Comment: Why would it matter if the IP is a private (RFC1819) address? Another interesting question is: from where does the PC get this DNS address? How is the network configuration set on the PC; is the RPi working as a DHCP server, or is the IP configuration static on the PC? If the RPi functions as a router, then the PC can't use a DHCP server on the wlan side.